# TFS API - minTime filter not working

Tags: api, tfs

Is there an API version level that is required for the minTime parameter to work?

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=3.1&minTime=?????
```

We run TFS api ver 3.1 on premise and minTime does not seem to work for us.

It would be great to know what parameters are available for what api version.

The documentation says that 4.1 supports this parameter:

```
maxTime query       
string
date-time   
If specified, filters to builds that finished/started/queued before this date based on the queryOrder specified.

minTime query       
string
date-time   
If specified, filters to builds that finished/started/queued after this date based on the queryOrder specified.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the `minTime` and `maxTime` parameters are supported since `api-version=4.1`.

Please see the REST API : [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) for details. It mentions all the available [URI Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1#uri-parameters) with the `api-version=4.1`.

In your scenario, **TFS 2017 does not support the `api-version=4.1`**. It only supports api ver `3.xx` and earlier versions (`1.0`, `2.0`). Please see [REST API Versioning-Supported versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=vsts#supported-versions) for details.

So, if you want to use the `minTime` and `maxTime` parameters you can upgrade to TFS 2018 or migrate to VSTS.

Alternately you can use other tools to filter builds by date, for example you can filter in PowerShell with calling the REST API.

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",  
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/build/builds"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET  -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$builds = $result.value | Where {$_.finishTime -ge '2018-05-24' -and $_.finishTime -le '2018-05-29'} # Filter builds by finish time between '2018-05-24' and '2018-05-29'
```

[image]

Comment: Where can I find out what parameters are available for each version?  That is my challenge.  There is no point in my implementing API calls using parameters our current install does not support.  And yes, an upgrade is always nice, but that's a project.  That is not something I can just do on whim.  At least not where I work. lol

Comment: I can't get minTime to work using VSTS and api-version=4.1. No where in the documentation does it seem to describe the string format required for minTime. I have tried the obvious formats, but I either get all builds back, or none.